# How do I successfully use functions declared inside the jQuery "ready" function?

Tags: jquery

I'm having a bit of a jQuery problem.  Basically I have some functions that I need to place inside the ready function so that they have scope access to some of the objects initialized on document ready.  However, for whatever reason, no methods created seem to respond to any of the DOM objects' `onClick`.  I am forced to pull them outside the `$()`.  I'm sure there is some elementary point I'm missing here, but I can't seem to see it.  Any ideas?

FYI (to anyone interested) for this particular problem, I am working with datatables (http://www.datatables.net/) and need to provide a few functions access to the initialized table(s).

Best.

Comment: Yes, what you say doesn't make sense. See simple example - http://jsfiddle.net/P4FVn/ If you can edit this to show your problem it would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using inline `onclick` handlers, add your event handlers within the `$()`:

```
$(function () {
    //...functions here
    $('a.click-me').on('click', function () {
        //call function here for clicking on the link with the `click-me` class
    });
});
```

That way the click handlers have access to the variables inside the anonymous function that runs when `document.ready` fires.

Comment: I agree in principle. In specifics, if his implementation of DataTables does any DOM node destruction, he'll need to use `.on()` to delegate an ancestor listener instead of listening to self.

Comment: Well, I'm using a form and attempting to "short-circuit" the SUBMIT if JS is available.  So I basically do a "form.serialize" and submit the data then use a "successful" ajax return to then manipulate the table on the page.  The problem is that the button 'onClick="delete_item()"' method won't run unless I pull it outside.  Perhaps I should use a non-descript button instead of an official "submit"?

Comment: @GregPettit:  Yes, I need to actually remove nodes after successful backend deletion.

Comment: Jasper still has it right. You can bind to a "submit" button just fine; all you have to do is preventDefault() on the event.

Comment: Wow, it helps if your "preventDefault" ends in "()" ... *facepalm* ... Thanks.